# Is it possible to run a function in node js with click of a button ? Like angular 11 or JavaScript

Tags: node.js, function, button, server

i'm new to Node js. I have a file "app.js" , where i am creating a server and displaying an html page with a button to start another proxy server. So is it possible to call the node js function to start another server with a click of a button? or can i  add the function to that button like angular 11 or JavaScript ?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: i have tried adding another js file, tried with bind the function with button . nothing works. should i upload my whole code ?

Comment: Yes please, you have to be more specific to get help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: where is the button that you are talking about?